# The page cannot be displayed because an internal server has occured

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, vb.net

Sometimes while I am surfing on my site, it shows the "The page cannot be displayed because an internal server has occured." error. My site is hosted in a shared hosting service, the PL is ASP.Net 4.0, VB.Net as codebehind, and the db is MSSQL Server 2014.

Does this error have something to do with the concurrent connections? If not, any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Impossible to say without more information. 
I would enable [Application Insights](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/application-insights/) on the website in order to have a more detailed look at what is happening.

It will show you how often you have errors, and let you dive into each single error to see what kind of exceptions are being thrown. Also, knowing what else is going on with your website is a pure bonus :)

To add Application Insights to your website, simply right-click the project and choose "Add Application Insights", there's really nothing more to it.

NOTE: 
I do believe App Insights requires an Azure subscription. Not sure if you can use without.